# Limitation of vertica community edition over premium edition

Tags: vertica

what are the difference like security , encryption in Vertica community edition vs premium edition.I am not getting any proper focus over this comparison.

Comment: It seems there's an answer to your question (even though maybe outdated) - http://vertica-forums.com/viewtopic.php?t=91

Answer (score 5):

The features are [the same in both versions](https://my.vertica.com/register/).  The difference is that Community Edition (the free download) is limited to 1TB of data and 3 database nodes.  Premium edition licenses are priced by usage.

Comment: Sorry, but may I ask, how do I upload data in the community edition? I can play with VMart but it seems to be local (on 127.0.0.1). Thank you!

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey if you install the RPM on our own hardware then you can start with an empty database and load data using COPY.  (Or you can load VMart data as explained in the doc.)  If you're using the community-edition VM, I'm not sure how you adjust network settings so that the VM can see the data you want to load.  (I don't know a lot about the VM, I'm afraid.)

Comment: thanks maybe I'll try to create a database and see what happens. If not I'll install an Ubuntu VM and then directly install Vertica on top of it.